# Search Binary Tree function not work c++

Tags: c++

and I was trying to implement a binary searching tree:

```
template <typename T>
bool Tree<T>::search(TreeNode<T> *ptr, const T &key) {
if (ptr == 0) {
 cout<<"No such data: "<<key<<" in the tree"<<endl; 
 return false;
 }
else{
if (ptr->data == key) {
    cout<<"Find a node whose data is "<<key<<endl;
      return true;
} 
else if (ptr->data < key)  return search(ptr->leftPtr,key);

else  return search(ptr->rightPtr,key);
}
}
```

But the result always returns false no matter the tree contains the key value or not.
Can u guys help me check the code? I tried debug, but still do not know.

Thank you!

Comment: Consider the the following strict-order when coding this. if !((a < b) || b < a)) then a == b. You need no equality-check, provided your underlying type and data honors that ordering; just a less-than.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your traversal comparator for left-tree descending is backwards. As such, as soon as you incorrectly descend into the *right* tree you stand no chance of ever finding that value. Only the root, and root only, will ever be found correctly.

This:

```
if (ptr->data < key)
    return search(ptr->leftPtr,key);
else
    return search(ptr->rightPtr,key);
```

Should read like this:

```
if (key < ptr->data) // <== note key is LESS THAN node.
    return search(ptr->leftPtr,key);
else
    return search(ptr->rightPtr,key);
```

---

That said, consider this:

```
template <typename T>
bool Tree<T>::search(TreeNode<T> *ptr, const T &key)
{
    if (ptr == 0) {
        cout<<"No such data: "<<key<<" in the tree"<<endl;
        return false;
    }

    if (key < ptr->data)
        return search(ptr->leftPtr, key);
    else if (ptr->data < key)
        return search(ptr->rightPtr, key);

    cout<<"Found a node whose data is "<< key << endl;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! It finally works. But I still don't know why. I think the logic is the same.

Comment: @Zach_Cat Which logic? the alternate version I posted or the correction to your code I posted at the start of this answer?

Comment: @Zach_Cat it isn't the same. Notice there is no need for an overloaded equality operator `bool operator ==(const T& key)` Look closely at it. Ultimately the equality check saves at most *one* comparison (the last one). Otherwise you always have to do two no matter what. In your case you compare ==, then <, in my case, two <. Either works, but yours requires two overloaded operators (`==` and `<`). I hope that makes a little sense. Glad it works, though!